# Python Regex: How to match filenames with optional suffix? Why '(.*?)(\.suffix)?' doesn't work?

Tags: python, regex

I have filenames like this:

```
xxx 
xxx.suffix 
xxx 
xxx.suffix
```

I want to find all the xxx's (which could be anything but does not contain '.suffix') and get rid of the suffixes.

I tried (.*?)(.suffix)?. I want the first group to match anything non-greedily and the second group to be optional.

But this doesn't work. What I get is:

```
('', None)
```

I'm using Python, the code is:

```
patt = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\.suffix)?')
print patt.match(str).groups()
```

**Edit**: apparently endswith('.suffix') also works but I didn't know.

Comment: not quite sure i understand the problem you're trying to solve; can you split on whitespace first and deal with a collection of strings?

Comment: sorry each of these xxx and xxx.suffix is a string that I want to match using this regex. they are just filenames

Comment: a quirk of python's regex library is that "match" basically adds an implicit "^" to the beginning of your pattern (vs. "search") — see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match — oddly (imo), there's no matchFully that would add both a "^" and a "$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you made the first part non-greedy, it even matches the empty string at the start. And as the second part is optional, it is omitted, thus the `None`.

Another solution:

```
a = 'xxx xxx.suffix xxx xxx.suffix'
l = a.split()
patt = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\.suffix)?$')
print [patt.match(i).groups() for i in l]
```

prints

```
[('xxx', None), ('xxx', '.suffix'), ('xxx', None), ('xxx', '.suffix')]
```

Why? Because now, the regexp is anchored to the end of the string with the `$`.

- Depending on what you plan to do with the results, it might as well be useful to use

  ```
  patt = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\.suffix|)$')
  ```

  which brings you `''` instead of the `None`s. This eases re-assembling the strings.
- And, of course, it is the question if you really need regexes.

  ```
  print [p[:2] for p in (i.partition('.suffix') for i in l)]
  ```

  yields the same result

  ```
  [('xxx', ''), ('xxx', '.suffix'), ('xxx', ''), ('xxx', '.suffix')]
  ```

  and is much faster:

  ```
  >>> import timeit
  >>> timeit.timeit(lambda: [p[:2] for p in (i.partition('.suffix') for i in l)])
  2.1371913756093956
  >>> timeit.timeit(lambda: [patt.match(i).groups() for i in l])
  5.259215670919147
  ```

  The result is the needed time in seconds for 1000000 calls.

Answer (score 4):

The empty string is a valid match for your regex, so it's matching that on all input.

Add "$" (end-of-string) to the end of the regex indicate that you don't want more data in the string after a match.

```
>>> re.compile( r'(.*?)(\.suffix)?$' ).match("xxx.suffix" ).groups()
('xxx', '.suffix')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `endswith`?

```
>>> a = 'xxx xxx.suffix xxx xxx.suffix'
>>> a = a.split()
>>> a
['xxx', 'xxx.suffix', 'xxx', 'xxx.suffix']
>>> [s for s in a if s.endswith('.suffix')]
['xxx.suffix', 'xxx.suffix']
```

Comment: glgl explains it well. However, you should always choose methods over regular expressions as regualar expressions are far more costly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, you don't have to split at first. For explanation and regex-testing, debugging, etc. look here: http://regex101.com/r/aL7dQ2

```
a = """
xxx 
xxx.suffix 
xxx 
xxx.suffix
"""
patt = re.compile(r'(\S+?\b)(\.suffix)?')
patt.findall(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[('xxx', ''), ('xxx', '.suffix'), ('xxx', ''), ('xxx', '.suffix')]
```